# pointer function in struct

Tags: c

I have 4 files:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.h"


int main() {
    struct Fun *fun = (struct Fun*)malloc(sizeof(struct Fun));
    fun->a = 2;
    fun->b = 12;
    fun->Func = Plus();
    int result = fun->Func(fun, 8);
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0; }
```

main.h

```
    #ifndef MAN_H_
    #define MAN_H_

    struct Fun {
        int   a;
        int   b;
        int (*Func)(struct Fun *x,int y);

    };
```

header.c

```
    #include "header.h"

    int Plus(struct Fun *x, int y) {
        return x->a * x->b + y; };
```

header.h

```
    #ifndef HEADER_H_
    #define HEADER_H_

    #include "man.h"

    #endif /* HEADER_H_ */
```

when I build, I get a warning:

> ../main.c:12:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Plus’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>   ../main.c:12:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

if I run, it has no result.

But when I put all the code to main.c and edit `fun->Func = Plus();` to `fun->Func = Plus;` it works fine: no warning, and the result is 32.

Comment: Tip, don't cast the return value of `malloc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should provide a function signature for `Plus` in *header.h*, and also add an `#include "header.h"` in *main.c*, so that something is known about the `Plus` function when it's used in *main.c*.

In *header.h*:

```
int Plus(struct Fun *, int);
```

Without such a signature, when compiling *main.c* the compiler makes assumptions about the function: an implicit declaration. This implicit declaration won't match the actual function definition.

Also, changing `fun->Func = Plus();` to `fun->Func = Plus;` is still necessary: the first form assigns to your function pointer the result of an attempted function call, the second form is the correct way to assign a function pointer.

Finally, this is likely just a cut/paste omission, but *main.h* is missing an `#endif`.